# Deserialize XML with VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am successfully deserializing this XML but when I add the Metadata section in, as seen below, I don't know how to deserialize this in code.  I mean I don't know how to build my class properties, methods, attribution tags etc.

I have tried many combinations of things but the Metadata remains empty in my class after deserialization.  Not even sure if I am asking the right questions and my code is a little lengthy. I tried pasting it here but it says it's too long so I'm not sure how to paste all of it for anyone to see.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MainMenu xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MenuItems MenuGroup="Boilers">
    <SubMenuItem>
      <GUID>3ec6e759-270f-4cd1-a9b8-07b4c227d47b</GUID>
      <ComponentType>Boiler:HotWater</ComponentType>
      <DefaultName>Boiler - Hot Water</DefaultName>
      <EquipmentUsage>Supply</EquipmentUsage>
      <Picture>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEYAAABGCAYAAABxLuKEAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAABFdJREFUeF7tm89PE1EQx9vyQ8SCNSLWH5BGDWli1CKGFBRFMYgJBxIvmHggMfHcxANcSI8c/TM8cuTIyXD<Picture>
      <ImageName>hot_water_boiler</ImageName>
    </SubMenuItem>
    <SubMenuItem>
      <GUID>1a4ee747-c11b-4687-be41-73680c104934</GUID>
      <ComponentType>Boiler:Steam</ComponentType>
      <DefaultName>Boiler - Steam</DefaultName>

<!-- How to deserialize this Metadata section? -->

      <Metadata>
        <MetadataItem>
          <description>Design Flow Rate {m3/s}</description>
          <value>Autosize</value>
        </MetadataItem>
        <MetadataItem>
          <description>Design Pump Head {Pa}</description>
          <value>179352</value>
        </MetadataItem>
      </Metadata>

      <EquipmentUsage>Supply</EquipmentUsage>
      <Picture>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEYAAABGCAYAAABxLuKEAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAABFdJREFUeF7tm89PE1EQx9vyQ8SCNSLWH5BGDWli1CKGFBRFMYgJBxIvmHggMfHcxANcSI8c/TM8cuTIyXD0yNGjR44e1/mU3bK7vIVd7Nvuq2+ST3ZT2O7M972ZnX27zVmzZs1aj1peKLj0JcA7huN7y7a3t53NzU2<Picture>
      <ImageName>hot_water_boiler</ImageName>
    </SubMenuItem>
  </MenuItems>
</MainMenu>
```

Code I added list property to,

```
<XmlType("MenuItem")>
Public Class PECSubMenuItem

'NOTE: By NOT specifing any custom Metadata Attributes, fields will be created as an element by default.
 Private mGUID As String
 Private mPicture As Bitmap
 Private mMenuGroup As String
 Private mComponentType As String
 Private mDefaultName As String
 Private mImageName As String
 Private mEquipmentUsage As String
 Private mMetadataList As List(Of MetadataItem)
 Public Enum EquipUsage
  Supply = 0
  Demand = 1
  Both = 2
 End Enum
 Public Sub New()
  mGUID = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString
  mMetadataList = New List(Of MetadataItem)
 End Sub
 <XmlElement("Metadata")>
 Public Property Metadata As List(Of MetadataItem)

  Get
   Return mMetadataList
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As List(Of MetadataItem))
   mMetadataList = value
  End Set

 End Property
```

Code I added for new class.

```
<XmlType("MetadataItem")>
Public Class MetadataItem

 Private mvalue As String
 Private mdescription As String
 <XmlElement("description")>
 Public Property description As String

  Get
   Return mdescription
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As String)
   mdescription = value
  End Set

 End Property
 <XmlElement("value")>
 Public Property value As String

  Get
   Return mvalue
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As String)
   mvalue = value
  End Set

 End Property

End Class
```

Comment: I'm not an XML expert, but what's so special about this Metadata "section"? What makes it different from the other nodes?

Comment: These are the changes I made and so far the Metadata list is still empty after deserialization. Vincent, one very nuanced thing you say is "in your initial class".  Can you clarify term "initial class"?  Class PECSubMenuItem are list members of a list defined in class PECMenuItem and PECMenuItem are list members of a list defined in PECMainMenu.

Comment: The initial class is the class that the metadata should belong to (dependent on what the XML looks like). In this case it should belong to the class representing `SubMenuItem`, which it appears to do in your new code so it _should_ work. Let me fire up Visual Studio and I'll try it out.

Comment: It works fine for me. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another class called `Metadata` or `MetadataItem`:

```vb
<XmlType("MetadataItem")>
Public Class MetadataItem

    <XmlElement("description")>
    Public Property Description As String

    <XmlElement("value")>
    Public Property Value As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Description As String, ByVal Value As String)
        Me.Description = Description
        Me.Value = Value
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then in the parent class you need a property which is a list of the `MetadataItem` class. Use the [**`XmlArray`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**`XmlArrayItem`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes to specify the name of the list and its items:

```vb
<XmlArray("Metadata"), XmlArrayItem("MetadataItem")>
Public Property Metadata As List(Of MetadataItem)
```

---

You also have a problem in your XML: The `<Picture>` tag is never closed.

Right now your XML looks like:

```vb
<Picture>...<Picture>
```

But it should look like:

```vb
<Picture>...</Picture>
```

Comment: Vincent, could I send you my class module and XML? I followed you instructions and still no good result. I'll keep trying no matter.

Comment: One thing I notice is this. I set a breakpoint in the MetadataItem class and it never breaks execution during deserialization.

Comment: @Mark : Okay. I'll have a look at it tomorrow.